# Should I set the parent in the controller or is that a terrible idea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a Rails 4 project, and I have something that is working, but I'm concerned that it might be a bad idea.

I have an Organization class. An Organization has_many Events (and all Events belong to an Organization. None lack that parent.).

I want to have the events#index action show only the events for the organization that is specified, *and* I want to be able to create a new event from that index view, for that organization.

So, what I'm doing right now is setting @organization in the Events controller, before the :index action.

Here's how the code rolls:

```
../routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :organizations do
    resources :events
  end
end

../events_controller.rb

class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_organization, only: [:index]

....all the things....

private
  def set_organization
    @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
  end 

end

../views/events/index.html.erb
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Events</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>End date</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Organization</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @events.each do |event| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= event.start_date %></td>
        <td><%= event.end_date %></td>
        <td><%= event.location %></td>
        <td><%= event.organization_id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', event %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', event, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Event', new_organization_event_path(@organization) %>
```

The last line of the view, that "New Event" link, doesn't work if I don't preset @organization, although the URL does have the organization id in it (For example, http://localhost:3000/organizations/2/events/).

I'd appreciate the following kinds of feedback: 1) No, that's awful, do it this way and here's why, or 2) Totally fine, that's how I would do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I set the parent in the controller

Yes, your approach is totally fine. Always set the ***parent instance(the FK)*** in the controller and **don't** set it in `form` as `hidden_field`.